# Django aggregation/annotation

Tags: django, django-models, annotations, aggregation

I have (it's just an example) models like these:

```py
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)


class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)


TeamHasPlayer(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
```

I need to make a dictionary like this:

```py
{
    'Team_1': [Player_1, Player_2, ...],
    'Team_2': [Player_3, Player_4, ...],
    ...
 }
```

I thought it can be achieved with django annotation/aggregation tools, I read all the docs about it, tried many different approaches but I can't achieve what I want. Could anyone give me any hint? I don't want to do any asking-db-in-for-loop things so I decided to use aggregations/annotations.

Comment: You need a `dict` with with `team_ids` as keys and a list of `player` objects (or ids?) as value is that correct?

Comment: I need dict with Team name values and list players assigned to each Team name to be exact :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

1. You have a M2M relation between `Team` and `Player`, create it.

   ```
   class Player(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(...)

       teams = models.ManyToManyField(Team, through='TeamHasPlayer')
   ```
2. Get your `Team` queryset and using the reverse relation `prefetch` the `team.players`

   ```
   teams = Team.objects.all().prefetch_related('player_set')
   ```
3. Now create your team dict:

   ```
   team_dict = {}
   for team in teams:
       team_dict[team.name] = list(team.player_set.all())
   ```

Comment: Great! Until now I was trying to avoid ManyToMany relationship cause it looked complicated to me. Now I read more about it, thanks a lot Todor :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in this way, which is more readable and maintainable.

```
dic_ = {}
for team in Team.objects.all():
    dic_[team.name] = team.teamhasplayer_set.values_list('player', flat=True)
```